# Can't view saved data from SQLite database

Tags: java, android

```
public void viewAll() {
    btnHighScore.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                    if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                        return;
                    }
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while(res.moveToNext()) {
                        buffer.append("ID : " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("Firstname : " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("Lastname : " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    }
                    showMessage("High Score Table", buffer.toString());
                }
            }
    );
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```

You can see the full code here: [SQLite App](http://tpcg.io/QCUzQF)

[image: High Score Table]

I am having trouble to view the data saved on my database. I've upload the code here so someone can help me find the mistake I have made because I am getting no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in the link you need to get the firstname and lastname from the views. See line 142. Fetching the name values in `onCreate` the views are blank so your inserting empty strings into your database.

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String firstname = etfirstname.getText().toString();
        String lastname = etlastname.getText().toString();
        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertdata(firstname, lastname);
        if(isInserted == true)
            Toast.makeText(SaveData.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(SaveData.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```